# Is there a reason declval returns add_rvalue_reference instead of add_lvalue_reference

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, declval, reference-collapsing

changing a type into a `reference` to a type, allows one to access the members of the type without creating an instance of the type. This seems to be true for both `lvalue references` and `rvalue references`.

`declval` is implemented with `add_rvalue_reference` **instead of** `add_lvalue_reference`,

- is this just a convention,
- or are there examples of use where `add_rvalue_reference` is preferable?

Edit: 
I suppose I was slightly vague, these answers are all very good but touch on slightly different points. There are two different answers to use proposed, Howard emphasized that you can choose which reference your type has, making `add_rvalue_reference` more flexible. The other answers emphasize that the default behavior automatically chooses references which reflect the input type more naturally. I don't know what to pick! If somebody could add two simple examples, motivating the need for each property respectively, then I'll be satisfied.

Comment: "changing a type into a reference to a type, allows one to access the members of the type without creating an instance of the type." Where did you read that?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

With `add_rvalue_reference`:

- `declval<Foo>()` is of type `Foo&&`.
- `declval<Foo&>()` is of type `Foo&` (reference collapsing: “`Foo& &&`” collapses to `Foo&`).
- `declval<Foo&&>()` is of type `Foo&&` (reference collapsing: “`Foo&& &&`” collapses to `Foo&&`).

With `add_lvalue_reference`:

- `declval<Foo>()` would be of type `Foo&`.
- `declval<Foo&>()` would be of type `Foo&` (reference collapsing: “`Foo& &`” collapses to `Foo&`).
- `declval<Foo&&>()` would be of type `Foo&` **(!)** (reference collapsing: “`Foo&& &`” collapses to `Foo&`).

that is, you would never get a `Foo&&`.

Also, the fact that `declval<Foo>()` is of type `Foo&&` is fine (you can write `Foo&& rr = Foo();` but not `Foo& lr = Foo();`). *And that `declval<Foo&&>()` would be of type `Foo&` just feels “wrong”!*

---

*Edit:* Since you asked for an example:

```
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

struct A {};
struct B {};
struct C {};

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int) { } // (not default-constructible)

    A onLvalue()   &  { return A{}; }
    B onRvalue()   && { return B{}; }
    C onWhatever()    { return C{}; }
};

decltype( declval<Foo& >().onLvalue()   ) a;
decltype( declval<Foo&&>().onRvalue()   ) b;
decltype( declval<Foo  >().onWhatever() ) c;
```

If `declval` used `add_lvalue_reference` you couldn't use `onRvalue()` with it (second `decltype`).

Comment: Is there any other reason to distinguish `declval<Foo>` ( or `declval<Foo&&>` ) from `declval<Foo&>` other than the reference matching in member functions, when `Foo` is a user defined type ?

Comment: If declval<>() returns as rvalue reference of T, then doesn't declval<Foo >( ) return Foo&&? Why would it call onWhatever()?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, the use of `add_rvalue_reference` gives the client the choice of specifying whether he wants an lvalue or rvalue object of the given type:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>
#ifndef _MSC_VER
#   include <cxxabi.h>
#endif
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

template <typename T>
std::string
type_name()
{
    typedef typename std::remove_reference<T>::type TR;
    std::unique_ptr<char, void(*)(void*)> own
           (
#ifndef _MSC_VER
                abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(TR).name(), nullptr,
                                           nullptr, nullptr),
#else
                nullptr,
#endif
                std::free
           );
    std::string r = own != nullptr ? own.get() : typeid(TR).name();
    if (std::is_const<TR>::value)
        r += " const";
    if (std::is_volatile<TR>::value)
        r += " volatile";
    if (std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value)
        r += "&";
    else if (std::is_rvalue_reference<T>::value)
        r += "&&";
    return r;
}

int
main()
{
    std::cout << type_name<decltype(std::declval<int>())>() << '\n';
    std::cout << type_name<decltype(std::declval<int&>())>() << '\n';
}
```

Which for me outputs:

```
int&&
int&
```

Comment: That type name builder :)

Answer (score 5):

You want to be able to get back a`T`, a `T&`, or `const`/`volatile` qualified versions thereof. Since may not have a copy or move constructor, you can't just return the type, i.e., a reference needs to be returned. On the other hand, adding an rvalue teference to a reference type has no effect;

```
 std::declval<T>  -> T&&
 std::declval<T&> -> T&
```

That is, adding an rvalue reference type has the effect of yielding a result which looks like an object of the passed type!

Answer (score 3):

An example of where you need control over the returned type can be found in my [**df.operators**](https://github.com/d-frey/operators/) library, when you need to provide a `noexcept` specification. Here's a typical method:

```
friend T operator+( const T& lhs, const U& rhs )
  noexcept( noexcept( T( lhs ),
                      std::declval< T& >() += rhs,
                      T( std::declval< T& >() ) ) )
{
    T nrv( lhs );
    nrv += rhs;
    return nrv;
}
```

In generic code, you need to be **exact** about what you are doing. In the above, `T` and `U` are types outside of my control and the `noexcept` specification for a copy from a const lvalue reference, a non-const lvalue reference and an rvalue reference could be different. I therefore need to be able to express cases like:

- Can I construct `T` from a `T&`? (Use `T(std::declval<T&>())`)
- Can I construct `T` from a `const T&`? (Use `T(std::declval<const T&>())`)
- Can I construct `T` from a `T&&`? (Use `T(std::declval<T>())`)

Luckily, `std::declval` allows the above by using `std::add_rvalue_reference` and reference the collapsing rules.