# How does std::is_assignable work?

Tags: c++, c++11

Here's the implementation of [std::is_assignable](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/libstdc++/api/a01525_source.html), I have spent few hours trying to get how it can statically figure out the type of the templated object but couldn't.

In the standard `is_assignable` states that both sides of the assignment are converted to `std::add_rvalue_reference<T>::type`. I don't get that sentence nor see how `std::add_rvalue_reference<T>::type`can be used to predict the type of the object.

Would anyone be able to give me a simple explanation that I can use as a first step to understand how std::is_assignable works?

Comment: See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_assignable

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "predicting the type of the object". The types are specified through the template parameters.

Comment: yes but how would it know if a type is assignable to another type?

Comment: @Kam What about my answer doesn't satisfy that question?

Comment: @0x499602D2 nothing :) I just need a bit of time to go through it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the same code with some of the lexical obfuscation taken out:

```
 1043     template <typename Tp, typename Up>
 1044     class is_assignable_helper
 1046     {
 1047       template <typename Tp1, typename Up1>
 1048         static decltype(declval<Tp1>() = declval<Up1>(), one())
 1049         test(int);
 1050 
 1051       template<typename, typename>
 1052         static two test(...);
 1053 
 1054     public:
 1055       static constexpr bool value = sizeof(test<Tp, Up>(0)) == 1;
 1056     };
```

This class uses [SFINAE](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSubstitution_failure_is_not_an_error&ei=zK0oVJ_oLoayyQSrgoIw&usg=AFQjCNFZiKaK2Vh9x7OdzCq0MpA87_XU8w&sig2=Mk4VLbVF0PoHyZYIkFna3A) to do the dirty work. That is, the value of variable `value` will depend on which `test()` function is chosen based on overload resolution. One overload takes an integer and the other takes a C variadic argument (specified by the ellipsis). If there is a *substitution failure* that occurs on the first overload, the second overload will be chosen.

If a substitution failure *does* occur, it will have come from the expression `declval<Tp1>() = declval<Up1>()`. `declval<T>()` is a function declaration that "returns" a value of the type `std::add_rvalue_reference<T>::type`. This function is mainly used in unevaluated contexts like `decltype()`, `sizeof()`, `noexcept()`, etc, in order to get an instance of a type without explicitly calling a constructor (because that type may not have an accessible constructor). If you'd like to know why `add_rvalue_reference` is the chosen return type, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303250/is-there-a-reason-declval-returns-add-rvalue-reference-instead-of-add-lvalue-ref).

Once you get an instance of the type, you can call member/non-member functions on those instances. The member function used is `operator=()`. If a class doesn't have an assignment operator (or has an inaccessible one) there will be a substitution failure. The fallback (variadic) version of `test()` will instead be chosen.

The reason for the difference in argument types (`int` vs `...`) is because `...` has the lowest conversion rank and it acts as a "last resort" for overload resolution. We can't just leave the parameters empty or else we'll get a redeclaration error.

As for the return type of `test` - if a substitution failure does *not* occur (a value of type `Up` can be assigned to a value of type `Tp`) then `test()` returns a type indicating success. If a substitution failure does happen, the the fallback version that returns a type indicating failure is chosen. These types are differentiated through a check for their sizes. We check for success by comparing with `1`.

Comment: `==` is not the assignment operator.

Comment: *"in order to get an instance of a type without explicitly calling a constructor"* or destructor. -- `operator=()` needs a parameter

Comment: Ok I will need a bit of time to understand the answer, as few of the terms and methods used are not familiar to me. But thanks a lot

Comment: @dyp Not sure I understand the comment. Was that sentence inaccurate?

Comment: I don't get this sentence: 'template<typename, typename> static two test(...);' what is 'two'

Comment: @Kam `one` and `two` are typedefs such that `sizeof(one)` is 1 and `sizeof(two)` is 2.

Comment: @Kam In the original code `__is_assignable_helper` derived from `__sfinae_types` which most likely provided the `one` and `two` types (probably `char` and `char(&)[2]` respectively). Their sizes are what is important because they differentiate between success and failure.

Comment: You have been very helpul, thank you for the above, but I still don't get from your explanation how decltype(declval<Tp1>() = declval<Up1>(), one()) can figure out that Up1 is Assignable to Tp1 can you elaborate a bit more in the explanation of that part if you can?

Comment: `declval<T>() = declval<U>()` isn't actually assigning anything. Remember that `decltype` is an unevaluated context meaning the only thing it cares about are types, not values. If the assignment operator is not overloaded for those two types (or one doesn't exist or it's private, etc.) then a substitution failure will occur. When that happens that specific overload of `test()` is removed as a viable function for those two types, the second (last resort) overload is instead taken.

Comment: `declval` returns an rvalue-reference and not a prvalue to not require an accessible destructor. `operator=` needs a parameter, so it should be `operator=(A)`, but we do not know `A` (since there could be conversions). Both are minor remarks, you've already got +1 from me.