# std::declval and unevaluated expressions

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae, declval

With reference to the following example in  [Proposing Standard Library Support for the C++ Detection Idiom](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4436.pdf):

```
// primary template handles types that do not support pre-increment
template< class, class = void_t<> >
struct
has_pre_increment_member : false_type { };

// specialization recognizes types that do support pre-increment
template< class T >
struct
has_pre_increment_member<T, void_t<decltype( ++declval<T&>() )>> : true_type { };
```

how does the expression `++declval<T&>()` classify as unevaluated?

In the above, assuming `declval()` returns `T&` as discussed in [Is there a reason declval returns add_rvalue_reference instead of add_lvalue_reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303250/is-there-a-reason-declval-returns-add-rvalue-reference-instead-of-add-lvalue-ref)
, doesn't the result of the expression `++T&` (resulting from `++declval<T&>`) become odr-used as opposed to unevaluated? As per [ODR-use](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#ODR-use):

> a reference is odr-used if it is used and its referent is not known at
>   compile time;

In the above case, isn't the referent not known at compile time? In that case, how can the reference be used with `declval()` in the first place?

Comment: I think anything in `decltype()` is unevaluated.

Comment: This is the *point* of `std::declval`. You get to magic *anything* into existance within `decltype`, because it is only used in finding the *type* of an expression

Answer (score 3):

> how does the expression `++declval<T&>()` classify as unevaluated?

Because it's within [`decltype()`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple#4.sentence-3):

> The operand of the `decltype` specifier is an unevaluated operand.

A [function](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#7.sentence-2), [variable](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#4.sentence-1), [structured binding](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#5.sentence-1), [assignment operator or constructor](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#8),  etc. must appear in a **potentially evaluated** expression in order to be *odr-used*. `decltype()` doesn't meet that criteria.

Comment: I guess my original question was not phrased correctly. I have edited the original question to rectify this issue.

Comment: @user9196120 Answer doesn't change. Things within `decltype()` are unevaluated.