# Using declval with a reference type

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, declval

I see some code examples where the type used to instantiate the `std::declval` template function is specified as a reference type rather than just a type, as in:

```
std::declval<T &>()
```

as opposed to:

```
std::declval<T>()
```

where `T` is some type. I am missing the subtlety why the reference notation might be chosen overe the plain type. Would someone please explain this to me ?

I know that `std::declval` expands to `typename std::add_rvalue_reference<T>::type` but I am still missing the reason why one would instantiate the latter with a reference to a type rather than the plain type itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a reason declval returns add\_rvalue\_reference instead of add\_lvalue\_reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303250/is-there-a-reason-declval-returns-add-rvalue-reference-instead-of-add-lvalue-ref)

Comment: No. Enrico, that has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: what about my answer?

Answer (score 4):

Due to reference collapsing the result is different (see [the answer I linked in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303250/is-there-a-reason-declval-returns-add-rvalue-reference-instead-of-add-lvalue-ref)), and it does have consequences.

Think of the fact that memeber functions can be `&&`/`&`/`const&` qualified, for instance.

The following is a simple, even though probably meaningless, example of how passing `T` vs `T&` to `std::declval` can have a "drastic" effect.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
struct A{};
struct B{};

struct C {
    A f() && { return A{}; }
    B f() const & { return B{}; }
};
int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<A, decltype(std::declval<C>().f())>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<B, decltype(std::declval<C&>().f())>);
}
```

Comment: This is understandable, Enlico. Thanks !